# OR operator in SQL statment not giving proper results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an HTML search box which have an SQL query which should display data if the word matches any of 4 columns in table.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sample");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_REQUEST["search"])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_gallery WHERE key1 OR key2 OR key3 OR key4 LIKE ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

        $param_term = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';


        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){?>
```

SQL column

[image]

This is the complete SQL code, its displaying data sometimes only when word matches last column, doesn't display for first 3 columns when I type corresponding word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the conditions for each column and not just list columns.
 Change it like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM image_gallery 
WHERE key1 LIKE ?
   OR key2 LIKE ? 
   OR key3 LIKE ?
   OR key4 LIKE ?
```

Currently you fill your parameter value after you use it. Reverse that. Replace

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);
$param_term = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
```

with

```
$param_term = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $param_term, $param_term, $param_term, $param_term);
```

And your table structure is not normalized and should be changed. If you have numbers in your column names then you almost always do something wrong.

Comment: hey, i tried its but its showing me the following eroor "mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\view.php on line 143
ERROR"

Comment: Yes, you need to bind 4 parameters now and not just one.

Comment: i didnt understand, can  you please tell me in plain english or show in ur code

Comment: Currently you bind one parameter here: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);` But using my query you need to bind 4 parameters because you have now 4 `?` in your query which need to be filled.

Comment: @juergend It would be useful to show in your code how to bind more than one parameter. With mysqli it is not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as

Also if you match exact same then you can use `WHERE` without `LIKE`

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_gallery WHERE key1 LIKE ? OR key2 LIKE ? OR key3 LIKE ? OR key4 LIKE ?";
```